# How to change the property of a existing Html Control ? In Razor block

Tags: html, c#-4.0, razor

This in Html code:

```
    <div id="MyDiv" class="Active">
      <h3>Hello Sheebu</h3>
    </div>
```

In View Rager Engine code:

```
    @{
    var bool test=true;
    if(test==true)
    {
    //here set the class name from Active to In active of a existing div whose id is MyDiv.    
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
@{
  var test = true;
}

@if (test) {
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('MyDiv').className = 'Inactive';
  </script>
}
```